# Jquery: trying to hide and show on hover on multiple divs with same id plus number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get a div that looks like `<a id="thumblink-10">` to show and hide another div on hover, but no luck.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(document).find("a[id^='thumblink-']").live('hover', function(){
    var num = this.id.split('-')[1];

          jQuery('#thumb-hover-' + num).show();

    }, function(){
        //var num = this.id.split('-')[1];
          jQuery('#thumb-hover-' + this.num).hide();
    });



});
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use IDs or can you use a css class?

Comment: Btw, you state that you are trying to hover over one div to show another but your selector is looking for an a tag.

Comment: Yes sorry an a tag and divs to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
jQuery("a[id^='thumblink-']").live('hover', function(){
    var num = this.id.split('-')[1];
    jQuery('#thumb-hover-' + num).toggle();
});
```

Fixed the initial selector to not use find, only need to supply and single function for the hover and use the toggle function to show/hide the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zy2Ny/

But the way I would actually do it is to add data attributes to your links (can then change the selector to a class one instead) and use those to find the correct div to toggle like this:

JS

```
jQuery("a.thumblink").live('hover', function(){
    var num = $(this).data('contentid');
    jQuery('#thumb-hover-' + num).toggle();
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="thumblink" data-contentid="10">Hover</a>
<div id="thumb-hover-10" style="display: none;">Content</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zy2Ny/1/

Comment: Thanks never thought of using toggle(); but works great thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't really do traversal methods like `find` and then use `live`.  You should just use a standard selection. Also, you can't use `live` with `hover` and give two functions.

```
$("a[id^='thumblink-']").live('hover', function(){ // simple selector
```

Better still would be to use `delegate` and a map of events and handlers:

```
$(document).delegate('a[id^="thumblink-"]', {
    mouseenter: function() {

    },
    mouseleave: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: +1: Relevant piece of documentation: *DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector* (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test it unfortunately, but I believe the following should work:

```
var id = 10;
$('#thumblink-' + id).hover(function(id) {
        return function () {
            $('#thumb-hover-' + id).show();
        };
    }(id),
    function(id) {
        return function () {
            $('#thumb-hover-' + id).hide();
        };
    }(id)
);
```